# Azure Function with EventGridTrigger - Singleton Attribute not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-storage-queues

I try to set a `SingletonAttribute` to a Azure Function with a `EventGridTrigger`:

```
[Singleton("{Subject}")]
public void Run([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger logger)
{
    ...
}
```

Each subject should only run as singleton.
But I get error:

> [Error] Executed '[NameOfFunction]' System.InvalidOperationException :
> No value for named parameter 'Subject'.

`eventGridEvent.Subject` has a value. I can see it in log files, when I remove the Singleton.

When I send the `EventGridEvent` to a Azure storage queue and make the function with Queue Trigger, then it works.

```
[Singleton("{Subject}")]
public void Run([QueueTrigger("evengrid-debug", Connection = "MessageQueueStorage")] HubEvent hubEvent, ILogger logger)
{
    ...
}
```

Here also `hubEvent.Subject` has a value.

Answer (score 0):

***Try adding the Singleton value of subject directly during your runtime and use ILogger to eventGridEvent.Subject to like below:-***

**Code:-**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static class MyFunction
{
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    [Singleton("{Subject}")]
    public static void Run(
        [EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Received event with subject: {eventGridEvent.Subject}");

     //function code
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

*With my Eventgrid Trigger Function:-*

[image]

Comment: When I have the `[Singleton("{Subject}")]` then the function does not start. I get ther error. When I remove the singleton attribute, I can logge `log.LogInformation($"Received event with subject: {eventGridEvent.Subject}");`